# How to know which entry is duplicated? (For example username + email)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, unique-key

I would like to know if it is possible to get the column name that made the duplicate error on an INSERT ?

For example, with an unique key on username and another unique key on email :

```
    try{
        $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `table`(`username`,`email`)`VALUES('Superman','xxx@xx.com')");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        if($e->errorInfo[0] == '23000' && $e->errorInfo[1] == '1062'){
           throw new CustomException("Bla bla already exists");
          // How does we get the duplicated column and then display "Email already exists" or "Username already exist"
        } else {
          throw $e;
        }
    }
```

How does we get the duplicated column info and then display "Email already exists" or "Username already exist" instead of "Duplicate entry (ok but which one?)

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO how to get duplicated key column name for INSERT in MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837001/pdo-how-to-get-duplicated-key-column-name-for-insert-in-mysql-database)

Comment: There is one way you can do select query in db and check if this email or username already exists id exists then print message otherwise insert in db

Answer (score 0):

You can check value in db or grab colum name in the error message for your users.

```
try{
    $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `table`(`username`,`email`) VALUES ('Superman','xxx@xx.com')");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if (preg_match("/Duplicate entry .+ for key '(.+)'/", $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
        throw new CustomException($matches[1]." already exist");
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

also maybe you prefer to use **exec** command for "non result query string".

```
$affectedRow = $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO `table`(`username`,`email`) VALUES ('Superman','xxx@xx.com')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea. Didnt think that error could give me this info.
So it will result as this :

```
    try {
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,email) VALUES ("test", "test")');
        $result = $query->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        if( $e->errorInfo[0] == '23000' && $e->errorInfo[1] == '1062' ){
            if( strpos($e->getMessage(), 'username') == true ) $result = 'duplicate_username';
            elseif( strpos($e->getMessage(), 'email') == true ) $result = 'duplicate_email';
        } else {
            throw $e;
            $return = false;
        }
    }
```

Basically doing the job.

Thanks,